# Alerting on any new error message in Kibana

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, observability

We use the ELK stack for logging exceptions.

I want to trigger alerts whenever brand new exception logs appear, based on a specific filter condition. Currently, I have to manually check exception message and their occurrences over the past week to detect if it is a new issue.

Comment: any luck finding solution?, I have similar problem